# 'Expected unqualified-id' error in Objective C++

Tags: c++, xcode, objective-c++, nsimage

XCode 10.1 (default compiler) does not compile the code below

```
NSImage* image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];
image.template = NO;
```

The error code is below

```
...: error: expected unqualified-id
            { image.template = NO; }
                             ^
```

The file extension is **.mm** (Default - Objective C++). When I change the extension to **.m** (Default - Objective C), everything compiles correctly. For me it is inappropriate because I use mixed C++/Objective C source code and I am planning to include C++ headers to the file.

As far as I understand it is a compiler bug. It treats the setter as C++ template<>. Is there any workaround? Can I tell the compiler to treat the line as pure Objective C code?

Comment: I guess `[image setTemplate: NO]` could do the trick.